# How to get cell value from index path? - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have table view. For a particular cell I had set a tag value, now, In my methods, I'm receiving index path how can I access cell.tag using index path.

Comment: Do you want to access only tag or value of each cell ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath];
NSInteger tag = cell.tag;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
int yourCellsTag = [[yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] tag];
```